# Python playing sound on button release instead of button press

Tags: python, pygame, raspberry-pi-zero

At the moment when I press button on GPIO 27 a LED on GPIO 17 turns on but the sound file doesn't play.

It for some reason plays when the button is released?

I have tried pygame.mixer.music.load and pygame.mixer.Sound

```
import pygame
from gpiozero import LED, Button

pygame.init()


led = LED(17)
button = Button(27)

while True:
    if button.is_pressed:
        pygame.mixer.music.load("zelda.mp3")
        pygame.mixer.music.play()
        led.on()



    else:
        led.off()
```

I need it so on button press LED turns on and sound plays

Answer (score 0):

1. For some reason, you must make a display window for pygame(its size does not matter)(May be you have make that window in other part of your code)
2. `play()` function must have enough time to play, for example i put an `input` method in last line to pause program to get something form input , all of that is to give enough time to play music. If you remove that line music plays but just some nano seconds! i.e. practically it doesn't play.(in some debug environment like Pycharm you may hear something but out of that you don't)
3. > In a `while` loop like your code, it is completely OK to play music when you release the button **BUT WHY?** Because `play()`
   >   function stops when it reaches to another `play()` function, and in
   >   your `while` loop as long as you have not release the key, `play()`
   >   functions come after each other and want to start to play to music but
   >   when they want to play , next `play()` functions arrives . This
   >   process continues until the last `while TRUE` and it is the moment
   >   very little time before you release the key.

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
pygame.display.set_mode((200,100))
pygame.mixer.music.load("zelda.mp3")
pygame.mixer.music.play()

x=input()
```

Comment: @MichaelHarker I'm very glad that your problem solved. You can support me by voting me up and check my answer as correct on. Thanks in advance